# Getting strange structure file when zipping a directory using Java

Tags: java, zip

I wanted to zip a directory with files and subdirectories in it. I did this and worked fine but I am getting and unusual and curious file structure (At least I see it that way).

This is the created file: [image: Empty zip file] When I click on it, I see an "empty" directory like this: [image] but when I unzip this I see this file structure (Not all the names are exacly as they are showed in the image below):

```
 |mantenimiento
   |Carpeta_A
     |File1.txt
     |File2.txt
   |Carpeta_B
     |Sub_carpetaB
       |SubfileB.txt
     |Subfile1B.txt
     |Subfile2B.txt
   |File12.txt
```

My problem somehow is that the folder "mantenimiento" is where I am zippping from (the directory which I want to zip) and I dont want it to be there, so when I unzip the just created .zip file I want it with this file structure (which are the files and directories inside "mantenimiento" directory):  [image: Correct directory structure] and the other thing is when I click on the .zip file I want to see the files and directories just like the image showed above.

I dont know what's wrong with my code, I have searched but haven't found a reference to what my problem might be.

Here's my code:

```
private void zipFiles( List<File> files, String directory) throws IOException
{
    ZipOutputStream zos = null;
    ZipEntry zipEntry = null;
    FileInputStream fin = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedInputStream  in = null;

    String zipFileName = getZipFileName();

    try
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream( File.separatorChar + zipFileName + EXTENSION );

        zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        int len;

        for(File file : files)
        {
            zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file.toString());
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
            zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
            {
                zos.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("No fue posible zipear los archivos");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        in.close();
        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.close();
    }

}
```

Hope you guys can give me a hint about what I am doing wrong or what I am missing.

Thanks a lot.

Btw, the directory i am giving to the method is never used. The other parameter i am giving is a list of files which contains all the files and directories from the C:\mantenimiento directory.

Comment: can you share getZipFileName method.

Comment: That method implementation is very simple:                                       private String  getZipFileName method()
{ 
 String zipName;
 
 Date currentDate = newDate();
 
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH-mm-ss");
 
 zipName = formatter.format(currentDate);
 
 return zipName; 
}

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem with windows and zip files, where the created zip did not contain the entries for the folders (i.e. `/`, `/Carpeta_A` etc) only the file entries. Try adding ZipEntries for the folders without streaming content.

But as alternative to the somewhat bulky Zip API of Java you could use Filesystem (since Java7) instead. The following example is for Java8 (lambda):

```
//Path pathToZip = Paths.get("path/to/your/folder");
//Path zipFile = Paths.get("file.zip");

public Path zipPath(Path pathToZip, Path zipFile) {
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("create", "true");
    }};

    try (FileSystem zipFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("jar:" + zipFile.toUri()), env)) {
        Path root = zipFs.getPath("/");
        Files.walk(pathToZip).forEach(path -> zip(root, path));
    }
}

private static void zip(final Path zipRoot, final Path currentPath) {

    Path entryPath = zipRoot.resolve(currentPath.toString());
    try {
        Files.createDirectories(entryPath.getParent());
        Files.copy(currentPath, entryPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: I would like to try it with Java7 as you recomended but pitifully I have to work with Java 6. Anyway, I'll try this approach "Try adding ZipEntries for the folders without streaming content."

Comment: try creating a zip in windows and open it with a tool like 7zip or with java directly and list the entries. If I'm not totally wrong, there should be either entries denoting paths or they start with a / something like. But there certainly is a connection between how you create the entries of the zip and how windows may handle it (or not)